# Custom Data Validation. First input field must be lower than Second input field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to add custom validation when I have two input fields and second one must be greater than first input field. I want to create a schedule. So for example: A person can choose his working hours so I want to make sure that person cant begin work 18.00 and finish it (same day) 13:00.

Is there any "easy-way" to do it ? Here how my Entity class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HospitalSite.Database.Entities
{
    public class Schedule
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Doctor doctor { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Monday")]
        public bool Monday { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Tuesday")]
        public bool Tuesday { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Wednesday")]
        public bool Wednesday { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Thursday")]
        public bool Thursday { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Friday")]
        public bool Friday { get; set; }

        //Doctor working hours 
        [Required(ErrorMessage= "Input required for working hours")]
        [Range(8.00, 18.00, ErrorMessage="Time must be between 8.00 and 18.00")]
        public int BeginWork { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input required for working hours")]
        [Range(8.00, 18.00, ErrorMessage = "Time must be between 8.00 and 18.00")]
        public int EndWork { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with integers you could do something like this:

```
public class Schedule
{
    ...
    public int BeginWork { get; set; }
    public int EndWork { get; set; }



     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
         if (BeginWork >= EndWork )
         {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The end work needs to be later than the begin work");
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use IValidatableObject interface.
You will need to implement Validate method in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use your own custom Attribute... here you have a example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class EndWorkNeedToBeLaterThanBeginWorkValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    public EndWorkNeedToBeLaterThanBeginWorkValidationAttribute()
        : base("The end work needs to be later than the begin work")
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var endWorkProperty = context.ObjectType.GetProperty("EndWork");
        var beginWorkProperty = context.ObjectType.GetProperty("BeginWork");

        var endWorkValue = endWorkProperty.GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);
        var beginWorkValue = beginWorkProperty.GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);


        if (beginWorkValue >= endWorkValue)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("The end work needs to be later than the begin work", new List { "EndWork", "BeginWork" });
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```